# PDF of a random vector

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have two independent variables X and Y with CDFs
$$F_X(x)=x, \  F_Y(x)=x$$
such that $$0≤|x|≤1$$ I need to find the PDF of a random vector $(min(X,Y),max(X,Y))$.

---

I understand that I should take some derivatives of F's. 
I also can find CDF of $Z=max(X,Y)$ which as I see equals to $F_Z(z)=z^2$ and hence the PDF is $f_Z(z)=2z$. But I do not know how to deal with $min(X,Y)$ and moreover how to deal with a vector of two variables.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can use $\min(X,Y) + \max(X,Y) = X+Y$

Comment: @Winther Why am I using a sum?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the original distribution is simply uniform on $[0,1]$ for both $X$ and $Y$. $(min(X,Y), max(X,Y))$ is simply(almost) the uniform distribution on the lower right triangle of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$. Since the area of this triangle is half, the joint pdf would be equal to $2$ everywhere.

(Almost because the pdf on the diagonal will be at half the value in the rest of that triangle)

Comment: The value of the PDF on the diagonal is irrelevant (and can be taken to be 42 if one likes to) since the diagonal has Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: @Did I am not sure about the pedantics here. Is it true that $f(x) = 1$ on $[0,1]$ and $f(0.5) = 42$ represents the uniform distribution? When you say something has a <name>-distribution, are you referring to the cdf or the pdf?

Comment: I am sure about what you call the pedantics. Yes the function in your comment is a legitimate PDF of the uniform distribution on (0,1).

Comment: @Did Alright. Will update the answer. Thanks! Ok, yes that's a bit of a stupid edit :)